# JTable Row Header's Name Is The Name Of The Database Table Column

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

When I made my table, the (not hardcoded) Jtable's row header was set as

```
| Performance Title | Start Date | End Date | Start Time | End Time |
```

But after getting data from the database, it changed to

```
| perf_title | perf_sdate | perf_edate | perf_stime | perf_etime |
```

which is the column name from the database..

Here is my code:

```
    try{
       String qwe = "SELECT perf_title, perf_sdate, perf_edate, perf_stime, perf_etime FROM performances";
       rs=st.executeQuery(qwe);
       jTable3.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    }

    catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Help?

[image]

Comment: Don't use `DbUtils` to construct a `TableModel`, instead, use the model you've already created (with the column names you want) and populate it instead. See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

The basic code would be something like:

```
//  Create an empty TableModel with just the column names

String[] columnNames = {"Performance Title", "Start Date", "...", "..."};
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0)
{
    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int column)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
        {
            Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

            if (o != null)
            {
                return o.getClass();
            }
        }

        return Object.class;
    }
};

//  Get each row of data from the ResultSet and add it to the TableModel

while (rs.next())
{
    Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>(columns);

    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
    {
        row.addElement( rs.getObject(i) );
    }

    model.addRow( row );
}

JTable table = new JTable( model );
```